# SCP and Telnet between two Macs on same home LAN not working

Tags: macos, lan, home-networking, scp, telnet

I have two Mac laptops connected to my home router. My machine is at IP `192.168.0.11` whereas the 2nd machine is at IP `192.168.0.13`. I'm trying to `scp` a file from my machine (`*.11`) to the other machine (`*.13`):

```
scp ~/files/somefile.txt user2@192.168.0.13:/Users/user2
```

When I run this I get:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.13 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I try to see if there's even a plausible connection between the two machines:

```
telnet 192.168.0.13 22
```

Figuring SSH would be running for sure. This gives me:

```
Trying 192.168.0.13...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.0.13: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

**How can I troubleshoot this and get `scp` working?**

Comment: Two things to check: is SSH even running on `192.168.0.13`? What is the firewall config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow following step in the remote MAC and enable SSH services. After you can try copy via scp command.

System Preferences pane → Sharing applet → check the Remote Login checkbox. This will enable SSH, and in turn, SCP.

Answer (score 0):

You can start the service using the following command in the remote MAC laptop after you can try copy via scp command.

sudo launchctl load  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist